# Convert text to fluent icons in multi-value field

Tags: sharepoint-list, json, json-formatting

I have SPO list with a multi-value field, which is filled by a lookup list (other list on the same SharePoint). The values are the names of MS Fluent Icons. Now I want the names in that field to be converted to the corresponding icons.

**Unformatted column**

[image]

**My JSON code so far (which just produces a blank field :( )**

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",

"elmType": "div",
"style": {
  "flex-direction": "column",
  "align-items": "flex-start",
  "margin-top": "2px",
  "padding-right": "0px",
  "width": "100%",
  "overflow": "hidden"
},
"children": [
  {
"forEach": "IconIterator in @currentField", 
"elmType": "div",
"style": {
  "font-size": "24px",
  "color": "#333333",
  "vertical-align": "middle",
  "width": "24px"
},
"attributes": {
  "iconName": "[$IconIterator]",
  "title": ""
}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is largely correct, ***if*** you are talking about standard Lookup fields. This means the primary lookup field where the value comes from the "In this column" dropdown *(shown in the **red** box below).* However, SharePoint changes the format of the values when in a **projected field** *(those extra columns you select as shown in the **yellow** box below):*

[image: Column Settings for Lookup Column]

You can see how these types of fields are handled differently (for the exact same values) in the standard list view with no formatting applied:

[image]

In a multi-lookup field, the primary value will come back as an array and the `forEach` pattern you've employed works. Here is a slight modification *(to reference the subproperty of `lookupValue`)* to your JSON that will work in this case:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "margin-top": "2px",
    "padding-right": "0px",
    "width": "100%",
    "overflow": "hidden"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "IconIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "[$IconIterator.lookupValue]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

In a **multi-lookup projected field**, the values will come back as a single string with multiple values separated by a space and a semi-colon. In this case, the `forEach` cannot be used. Even sadder, there isn't yet a split operation that would allow us to work with the values as expected. In this case, we have to get creative with a series of conditional elements that are extracting values using a complex combination of `if`, `substring`, and `indexOf` operators. This approach does work but has some drawbacks:

- It's super complex to read/write
- It can only handle a fixed set of values with each value having increasingly complex formulas to extract those values

Here is a reworked version of your JSON that accomplishes this for up to 5 values:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "style": {
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "margin-top": "2px",
    "padding-right": "0px",
    "width": "100%",
    "overflow": "hidden"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(@currentField,';')>=0,substring(@currentField,0,indexOf(@currentField,';')),@currentField)"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField,'inherit','none')",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')>=0,substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),0,indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')),substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000))"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(indexOf(@currentField,';')>=0,'inherit','none')",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')>=0,substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),0,indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')),substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000))"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')>=0,'inherit','none')",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')>=0,substring(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),0,indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')),substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000))"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')>=0,'inherit','none')",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(indexOf(substring(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')>=0,substring(substring(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),0,indexOf(substring(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')),substring(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000))"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(indexOf(substring(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),indexOf(substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField,';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')+2,1000),';')>=0,'inherit','none')",
        "font-size": "24px",
        "color": "#333333",
        "vertical-align": "middle",
        "width": "24px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the formats side by side:

[image: formatted columns with same display]

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort. I was afraid it had to do with these projected values... So I guess there's no other way to use the text in the lookup column in the form and show the icon values in the list? :-|

Comment: There's a PnP Sample that illustrates the above that may be worth looking at for anyone with similar requirements: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-lookup-projected-field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "block"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "forEach": "myIcon in @currentField",
      "txtContent": "",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=[$myIcon.lookupValue]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Before Applying JSON formatting

[image]

After applying JSON formatting

[image]